# what's the problem in this ascii char to hex c program?

Tags: c

As you can see, I am trying to make a program that receives `getche()` and then
show it and its hex and finally putting all ´getche()´es into a string but
that resulted in printing garbage chars!

Can you tell me what's the problem?

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {

    char allchars[64];

    int ctr = -1;

    char ch = 'a';

    while (ch != '\r') {
        printf("\nType a character:");
        ch=getche();
        printf("\nhex=%x\nch=%c",ch,ch);
        ctr++;
        allchars[ctr] += ch;
    }
    char terminate = 'a';
    printf("\nAll what you typed: %s",allchars);
    printf("\nPress any key to continue:");
    terminate=getche();
    if(getche()=='\n'){
        exit(0);
    }


}
```

output:

```
Type a character:t
hex=74
ch=t
Type a character:e
hex=65
ch=e
Type a character:s
hex=73
ch=s
Type a character:t
hex=74
ch=t
Type a character:
hex=d
ch=
All what you typed: ä{│t
Press any key to continue:
Process returned 13 (0xD)   execution time : 21.835 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: `allchars[ctr] += ch;` Why do you do `+=`? Looks like it's supposed to be `=`. Also, to use `%s` you need a string which means `allchars` needs to be NUL terminated: `allchars[++ctr]='\0';`

Answer (score 2):

First of all 'allchars' is not null terminated (add a '\0' at the end of the char array).

What do you think this expression does?

```
allchars[ctr] += ch;
```

Since you do not initialize 'allchars' with any value beforehand, the value at the index 'ctr' is unknown (could be anything), but you add the character 'ch' to it (add equal).

As a result, you will have garbage at that index, at least not that what you expect it to be.

At last: what if you type more than 64 characters?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your code, and a few other issues.

First, your line `allchars[ctr] += ch;` is *adding* the value of `ch` to the **uninitialized** existing value of the element of that array; you should use the simple assignment operator, instead: `allchars[ctr] = ch;`.

Second, all character strings in C that are to be used by functions like `printf` (with the `%s` format specifier) **must** be terminated with the `NUL` character (a zero value); so you need to add that after your `while` loop.

Another *probable* error (depends on your compiler/platform) is that you have not included the `<stdio.h>` header file - so there is no formal declaration of the `printf` function.

And, finally (I think), you really should be declaring your `main` function as returning an `int` (not `void` - although that is allowed, and was more common in days past).

Here is a version of your code with the above changes made (and commented):

```c
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> // MUST include this for the "printf" function

int main(void) // Should really use "int" return type
{
    char allchars[64];
    int ctr = -1;
    char ch = 'a';
    while (ch != '\r') {
        printf("\nType a character:");
        ch = getche();
        printf("\nhex=%x\nch=%c", ch, ch);
        ctr++;
        allchars[ctr] = ch; // Just assign! (Don't add to unitialized existing value.)
    }
    allchars[ctr + 1] = '\0'; // We MUST add a NUL-terminator to use the "%s" format

    char terminate = 'a';
    printf("\nAll what you typed: %s", allchars);
    printf("\nPress any key to continue:");
    terminate = getche();
    if (getche() == '\n') {
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Also, I missed the fact that you don't check for 'overflow' (user entering more than 64 characters). However, I won't edit this in, as that point has been made in the [answer given by Erdal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64909619/10871073).

Comment: thank you it worked I know I am always a noob 